# Git push is failing with pre-receive hook declined

Tags: git, gitlab

From my origin, I have cloned 2 local repositories on my machine. The first repository works fine, but the second repository is not allowing me to perform any push. It fails with:

```
 ! [remote rejected]       DF-abc -> DF-abc (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.abc.net:myusername/PR.git'
```

I have tried -f (force push)

```
git push -v --progress "origin" DF-abc:DF-abc
```

Comment: Have you tried everything suggested here already? https://github.com/progrium/gitreceive/issues/36

Answer (score 3):

When your Git reports "pre-receive hook declined", it means *their* Git ran a program of their own devising—probably a shell script, but it could be a Python script, or any other program—and *that program* told *their* Git not to accept the push.

Whatever program this is—I'll just call it "the pre-receive script"—it *should* have told you *why* it does not like you and/or your commits and what you should do to make it like you and/or your commits.  If it *didn't* tell you why, well, we can't either.  Only whoever controls this script can do anything about this.

If you control the machine `gitlab.abc.net`, you should log in to that machine and fix your pre-receive script.  Otherwise, you literally *can't* fix this: you must get hold of whoever controls the machine (and hence controls this script) and have them fix the problem.  Note that there are two parts to this fixing:

- telling you what you need to do on your end to make the script like you and/or your commits; and
- fixing the script so that *it* tells you this.

Doing the latter will achieve the former, although you would have to try again (and this time get the output *from* the script that tells you why it doesn't like you, and what you can do about it).

Comment: This was not a server/user error , but a GIT Lab issue. Please see the details below.

Comment: @user1485472: GitLab *is* the server. "Their" Git is the GitLab Git. The issue needed to be fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the existing GitLAb. This was solved by installing GITLab 11.8

Here are the actual details from the GIT lab development team:

Gitlab Issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/57067
Gitlab Merge Request: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/9569